# Diferentes documentos firebase con flutter y dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Tengo una coleccion en Firebase y esa coleccion tiene varios documentos. Mi pregunta es, como puedo acceder a los datos de cada uno de esos documentos?

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('apps').snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
          return new Text('Loading...');
        default: 
          print(snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) => print(document.documentID)));}})
```

De esta manera obtengo el id de todas los documentos de la coleccion 'app', pero quiero acceder a los datos de cada coleccion

Comment: Hola te recomiendo este video que hicimos en The Dart Side, donde tocamos Firestore para listar, editar, agregar y eliminar:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ogXEriEdMDU

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener los documentos de la coleccion **"apps"** nesesitas utilizar el metodo `get()` el cual nos devovlera los mismos.
El `querySnapshot.docs` devolverá un, `List<DocumentSnapshot>` por lo tanto, podemos iterar usando `forEach()`, que contendrá una devolución de llamada con un parámetro de tipo `DocumentSnapshot` y luego podemos usar la propiedad `data` para recuperar todos los datos de los documentos.

```
Firestore.instance.collection("apps").get().then((querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
        // print('Firestore: ${result.data()}');
      });
    });
```

De todas formas te dejo un link de un blog con buena referencias y formas de usos: [CRUD en FireStore](https://ichi.pro/es/como-usar-cloud-firestore-en-flutter-174444485265984)

saludos y espero te sirva